# ngModel resets the value every time the [value] is sent to the ts

Tags: html, angular, ngmodel

Every time I try to send data to the ts file the ngModel resets the selection in the dropdown.

```
 <select placeholder="select" class="custom-select"  id=" 
 {{entity.parameterDisplayName}}"
 [(ngModel)]="entity.parameterValue"
 name="{{entity.parameterDisplayName}}">
 <option [value]="-1"  [selected] ="true">Select Registration Type</option>
 <option  *ngFor="let regTypeValue of registrationTypeList"
 [ngValue]="entity.parameterValue" [value]="regTypeValue"  
 [selected]="regTypeValue">{{ regTypeValue }} </option></select>
```

I have tried using [select] and onClick as well, However as the date is being transferred successfully, And the selection from the drop down is being reset every time I click on search button below. Which will send all the information from the data filled from the form.

As modifications can be done and be searched again. The selections on the form needs to stay Put. And all the data is static, But the dropdown resets itself, Please suggest me how to stop it from getting reset.

Please help

Thanks in Advance

Comment: what are you doing inside the function `postRequestAndFetchResult` and why aren't you passing the entire form using `postRequestAndFetchResult (f)` and instead just passing a boolean using `postRequestAndFetchResult (f.form.valid...)`

Comment: As the function accepts the postRequestAndFetchResult(isValid: boolean, moduleName: String).

Comment: `postRequestAndFetchResult` is not an inbuilt angular function, this code must be written by you and must be present in the component.ts. Are you using any other libraries?

Comment: Yes, A function has been written by a colleague of mine , I need to send the form values to the function, Which I am able to send it. However the issues lies with the dropdown.

Comment: I've updated my answer, please try it and let me know if it works.

Comment: I have tried it, And the data is being transferred. As you have mentioned , However the dropdown issue still persists, Everytime I click on search, The dropdown goes to empty.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225353/discussion-between-link-and-abrar-ahmed).

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**

I believe this is where the problem is, please update your button code with the following and try again. You need to specify the button type as "submit" for the Search Button and also remove the click event from there because that is what the `(ngSubmit)` is there for, you shouldn't explicitly bind the `(click)` event when using `(ngSubmit)`

```
      <button
        type="reset"
        class="btn btn-secondary pl-4 pr-4 mr-3"
        (click)="reset();">
        Reset
      </button>
      <button
        type="submit"
        class="btn btn-primary pl-4 pr-4"
        [disabled]="!searchButtonEnabled"
        ng-disabled="loginform.$invalid">
        Search
      </button>
```

**Before EDIT:**

[(ngModel)] is not the reason your form is being reset, like you have said, you are clicking on a button in order to send the form data:

> And the selection from the drop
> down is being reset every time I click on search button below. Which
> will send all the information from the data filled from the form.

That is happening because button type 'submit' will refresh the page, that is HTML behavior, in Angular you don't submit forms like that, you need to use either `Template Driven Forms` or `Reactive Forms` approach and bind the `(ngSubmit)` event to a function.

In the below example, #f is a local reference and we are passing in `ngForm` to the local reference. This local reference is being passed into the `onSubmit(f)` function which then can be accessed as an argument in the `component.ts` file.

```
 <form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)" novalidate>
      <input name="first" ngModel required #first="ngModel">
      <input name="last" ngModel>
      <button>Submit</button>
    </form>
```

Here's official angular documentation on how to use Template Driven forms:
[Template Driven Forms](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgForm)

Comment: I have added the  (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)  novalidate as the <form #f="ngForm" was already added, However I am having the same issue. Not literally "onSubmit(f)  novalidate , The method that is being called when I click on search button. Still the issue persists. !

Comment: You will need to show more of your code for me to be able to help in spotting the issue. Can you update your question to include the Template's entire `<form> </form>` section and the `component.ts` file as well? Also you can remove `novalidate` if you want, it has nothing to do with `Angular`. `novalidate` is HTML syntax.

Comment: Also, try to remove the banana binding from `ngModel`. Instead of writing it like this `[(ngModel)]`, write it like this instead `ngModel`. or use property binding like this `[ngModel]` if needed.

Comment: I have updated the code, However most of it is irrelevant. Please take a look and let me know . Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that inside the select you are using `ngModel` for every option.
You have to use the `ngValue` directive like so:

```html
<form #f="ngForm">
  <select name="test" [(ngModel)]="selectValue">
    <option [ngValue]="1">1</option>
    <option [ngValue]="2">2</option>
    <option [ngValue]="3">3</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

here is a [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-1rdztm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html).

The ngModel registers a control with the Form element and the individual options are not separate controls because they are part of the select control.

So your code should look like (btw whenever you bind attributes to the individual elements you should use [] in favour of the [interpolation syntax](https://angular.io/guide/interpolation) {{}} because it interpolates everything to a string and sometimes you would want to have a number, so my suggestion is - use the {{}} outside tags):

```html
<select [id]="entity.Name" [(ngModel)]="entity?.parameterValue || -1" class="custom-select" [name]="entity.Name">
  <option [ngValue]="-1">Select Registration Type</option>
  <option  *ngFor="let rgValue of rgList"
  [ngValue]="rgValue">{{rgValue}}</option>
</select>
```

When using template driven forms I still haven't found a case where I would need "two-way data binding". The `ngModel` holds the value for each form control internally so in my opinion it's not good to have to manage the information in two places. You can just use `[ngModel]` without the `()` to bind the value to the control and then whenever you submit you can get the value from the form reference that the template variable `f` holds (in the example that I showed #f="ngModel")

```html
<form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="submitHandler(f.value)">
  <select [id]="entity.Name" [ngModel]="entity?.parameterValue || -1" class="custom-select" [name]="entity.Name">
    <option [ngValue]="-1">Select Registration Type</option>
    <option  *ngFor="let rgValue of rgList"
  [ngValue]="rgValue">{{rgValue}}</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Comment: I have tried using the ngValue, However using the value does not transfer the selection made from the dropdown, I have uploaded the complete code, Could you please take a look. Thanks

Comment: @Mr.R0bot I've just checked the [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-1rdztm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)  that I've provided and everything is working as it should. I'm not sure how it's not working on your side. In the code that you've showed you have to remove everything and just leave the `ngValue`. You shouldn't use the `selected` or `value` attributes. 

**BTW I've just saw that I made a mistake. You should have ` [ngValue]="rgValue"`. Take a look at the code in my answer (I've updated it)**

Answer (score 0):

Try one way binding of ngModel.

```
[ngModel]="entity.parameterValue"
```